# recvfrom: Resource temporarily unavailable. Why?

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking, recvfrom

I'm running this piece of code several times (for a non-blocking `recvfrom` on a **UDP socket**):

```
struct timeval read_timeout;
read_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
read_timeout.tv_usec = 1000;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &read_timeout, sizeof read_timeout);
ssize_t n = recvfrom(sockfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline), 0, NULL, NULL);
if (n < 0) {
    perror("recvfrom");
    return -1;
} else // ... normal usage
```

Sometimes the program stops and I get the following error from `perror`

> recvfrom: Resource temporarily unavailable

What could the issue be?

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for your answer. I understand what the problem is, but how can I solve it? Can I ignore this problem and loop with recvfrom again?

Comment: Increase the timeout or make it completely blocking (if possible).

Comment: @ikegami that means that actually I didn't understand the problem! I thought that using `setsockopt()` in such a way would simply let me skip the `recvfrom` if I wasn't receiving anything and go on with the following code... not making it return with an error!

Comment: Comments are not for new questions. Existing questions are not for new questions.  If you have a question to ask, click [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the code to do what you want. When you get an error, instead of calling `perror` unconditionally, check if it's a timeout. If it's not a timeout, then call `perror` and return. If it's a timeout, do whatever it is you want to do when you get a timeout.